# pdflatex not found. pdflatex is needed for pdf output

Tags: pdftex, ubuntu, pandoc, markdown

I have installed my shiny server on Ubuntu. In addition I installed Texlive- full 2017 on the server as well. The problem is that downloading report from the shiny app on the server does not work (on my local computer is working !!!) the error is :

```
pandoc: pdflatex not found. pdflatex is needed for pdf output.
Warning: Error in : pandoc document conversion failed with error 41
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081991/rmarkdown-pandoc-pdflatex-not-found) steps as well to create the symbolic link, but nothing has changed !

my pdflatex is in this path :

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux
```

so I have create the symbolic linke like :

```
ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux  /usr/texbin
```

and I have added the `/usr/texbin` to the path. Can anyone could tell me what I am missing here ?!!

Comment: your symbolic link syntax is wrong (you need to link pdflatex not the directory) but it is simpler to just put `usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux` in your PATH

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have it in my path as well : `echo $PATH`
`/usr/texbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/ali/:/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux`

Comment: but is pandoc looking for pdflatex on the path (in which case it would find it) or by /usr/texbin/pdflatex or similar? (in genral it's better to put the texlive one first in the path , what does `which pdflatex` if you enter that on the commandine?

Comment: `which pdflatex`
`/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex`